# Проверка корректности ввода данных

Tags: c, циклы

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Нужно считывать дату, месяц, год, пока юзер не введет правильные данные.

```
do {
    printf("\tДень: ");
        scanf("%d", &buf[N].nadhod.day);
    } while (buf[N].nadhod.day > 31 && buf[N].nadhod.day <1);

    do {
        printf("\tМесяц: ");
        scanf("%d", &buf[N].nadhod.month);
    } while (buf[N].nadhod.month > 12 && buf[N].nadhod.month < 1);

    do {
        printf("\tГод: ");
        scanf("%d", &buf[N].nadhod.year);
    } while (buf[N].nadhod.year > 3000 && buf[N].nadhod.year < 1800);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо && поставьте ||

```
do {
printf("\tДень: ");
    scanf("%d", &buf[N].nadhod.day);
} while (buf[N].nadhod.day > 31 || buf[N].nadhod.day <1);

do {
    printf("\tМесяц: ");
    scanf("%d", &buf[N].nadhod.month);
} while (buf[N].nadhod.month > 12 || buf[N].nadhod.month < 1);

do {
    printf("\tГод: ");
    scanf("%d", &buf[N].nadhod.year);
} while (buf[N].nadhod.year > 3000 || buf[N].nadhod.year < 1800);
```